# Which event is fired when back button is pressed while keyboard is open in android in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

OnBackButtonPressed() is not hitting when pressing back button while keyboard is open.

Need to unfocus the entry when keyboard hides using back button.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: are you putting your code OnBackButtonPressed() in ViewModel ? Try put in Code Behind

Comment: Thanks...but i added in Code behind..

Answer (score 1):

The `OnBackButtonPressed` is only called when a physical hardware back button is pressed. Since iOS has no such thing this will never be called on iOS. Each `Page` does have `OnAppearing` and `OnDisappearing` events that you can override on both platforms that allow you to do work when a view is going off-screen.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    // Do some work here
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    // Do some work here
}
```

Comment: Thanks...but i was asking about android

Comment: Like I also said, for Droid the event you mentioned only triggers for the hardware back button. There is no software back button equivolent unfortunately.

Comment: ok..but the hardware back button also does not trigger this event when keyboard is open...